# Geometric construction of golden angle

Tags: geometric-construction, golden-ratio

Is it possible to construct the golden angle using only a compass, ruler and pencil?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by golden angle?

Comment: Take the circumference of a circle, split it by the golden ratio, and it creates two angles. The smaller one is called the golden angle. Approx 137.51 degrees.

Comment: In other words, you are asking whether $e^{i (\sqrt{5}-1) \pi}$ is a *constructible number*. Good question, intuitively, I would say that it's not. [According to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos((sqrt5+-1)pi)) the answer is no.

Comment: What on Wolfram states its not a constructable number? Just so I understand...

Comment: Well, WA says "$\cos ((\sqrt{5}-1) \pi)$ is a transcendental number". It is a classic result that transcendental numbers cannot be constructed by means of ruler and compass.

Comment: This appeared on the arXiv tonight: https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10818 /The Golden Angle is not Constructible/ Pedro J. Freitas

Comment: Please add this as an answer